# Php mysql query for data from two tables

Tags: php, mysql, database

i have two tables in my database. table A is USERS and table B is relations, and the following are their columns 
USERS(username, avatar, specialty) and RELATIONS(username1, username2, reldir)
RELATIONS stores the relationship between users, that is if, username1 is following username2, reldir = F, and if they are both following each other, reldir=FB and vice versa, this part has worked very well but

i need to query these tables so that i return a list of users from USERS which for example user A doesnt follow but have the same specialty as A...

i tried this, but its not working well ...

$spec = the specialty of user A

```
SELECT a.username, a.avatar, a.specialty FROM users a, relations b WHERE a.username!=b.username2 AND (b.reldir!='F' OR b.reldir!='FB') AND a.speciality ='$spec'
```

the query to me seems logically correct but i could be wrong. i need help

Comment: In MySQL, there is no `!=` operator.

Comment: In MySQL both `!=` and `<>` are `not equal operators`, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some keys for your tables, because you have two different tables and they doesn't linked.

For example, table `USERS`:

```
id (as primary_key), username, avatar, specialty
```

Table `RELATIONS`:

```
user_id, username2, reldir
```

user_id - it is field "id" from table USERS (instead your "username1")

Then you will be able create a query like this:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM users a, relations b 
WHERE a.id = b.users_id 
  AND (b.reldir != 'F' OR b.reldir != 'FB') 
  AND a.speciality = '$spec'
```

ps: if I understood your question in the right way)

Comment: @sbmxal, thank you, but username is already the key of USERS and in your query at (a.id=b.users_id) , unfortunately this is incorrect since i need to filter off the names which A follows, and return those A doesn't follow so we should leave it as a.username!=b.username2,

so i edited the query and made it (SELECT a.* FROM users a, relations b WHERE a.username!=b.username2 AND (b.reldir!='$f' OR b.reldir!='$fb') AND a.username!='$u1' AND a.specialty ='$spec')

............$fb = 'FB'; $f ='F'; $u1 = username of A
it works but it still returns names that A follows already